# Check Worksheet that has same names from Multiple Workbooks using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, comparison

I don't know how to explain this, but I'm trying to create a Comparison Tool using Powershell.
I have Multiple Source Files with multiple worksheets that has same names with the other Source files.

My problem is how to get the contents of every worksheet under the same worksheet names and paste it in the Output File and generate a new Worksheet with a same name as the Source Worksheets.

So far I have this, and it works on copying the contents of each worksheets.  But I'm having error on worksheet renaming because it's already existing. I already have the idea by putting an "If statement" but it confuses me on what condition to put.

```
ForEach($File in $Files){
$Source = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File,$true,$true)
$SourceSheets = $Source.Worksheets

For ($i = 1; $i -le $SourceSheets.Count; $i++){
    # Select the current sheet of the Source
    $currentSheet = $Source.Sheets($i)
    # Copy the desired Range
    $currentSheet.Range("L6","M$(($currentSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()

    # Add a new worksheet in Output and Rename it same as with the Source sheets
    $OutputSheet = $Dest.Worksheets.Add()
    $OutputSheet.Name = $Source.Sheets.Item($i).Name

    If ($OutputSheet.Name is already existing){
        Paste the Copied Contents from Source and Paste it in OutputSheet
    } Else {
        Add new Worksheet
    }
    
    $Dest.SaveAs("$ParentFolder\Output Folder\SampleOutput.xlsx")
}
```

Worksheet in Source Files:

[image: Worksheets on Source Files]

Sample Template of Output File:

[image: Output File]

I'm having fun learning this so Thank you for taking time for this problem :)

Comment: You can target specific worksheets using the [`ImportExcel` module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel), it's as easy as `Import-Excel file.xlsx -WorksheetName sheetnamehere`, the output assuming the sheet only has one table, is the same as the output given by `Import-Csv` (an array of PsCustomObjects)

Comment: Hi :) I think it would not work since I have multiple Worksheets under 1 workbook. I don't want to specify the worksheet name. I was trying to iterate through every worksheet from Different Workbooks and put the contents of each Worksheet under 1 worksheet name that has the same name of each Source files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you would like to know how to loop through all sheets in a book.

```
# $source = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
#Loop through sheets
for ($i = 1; $i -le $source.Sheets.Count; $i++){
    $currentSheet = $source.Sheets($i)
    #Do something on $currentSheet
}
```

For the second question, I would do it like below.

```
# make a list for file you would like to look up
$files = @("File1.xlsx","File2.xlsx","File3.xlsx")
# loop through $files
for ($j = 0; $j -lt $files.Count; $j++){
    $FullPath = (Get-ChildItem -Path $files[$j]).FullName
    $source = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FullPath)
    #Do something on $source
}
```

I hope this helps.

#20-09-2022 add

For the another question, I would get the names of all sheets first.

```
# before the loop
$arraySheetNames = @()
# get all names
# if $outputFile not exists (make it later), you do not need following for-loop
for ($i = 1; $i -le $outputFile.Count; $i++) {
    $arraySheetNames += $outputFile.Sheets($i).Name
}

# in the loop
# check if the sheet already exists
if (-not $arraySheetNames.Contains($currentSheet.Name)) {
    # if the same name doesn't exist, add sheets and put 
    $OutputSheet = $Dest.Worksheets.Add()
    $OutputSheet.Name = $Source.Sheets.Item($i).Name
    $arraySheetNames += $OutputSheet.Name
}
```

Comment: Hi :) This helps! one thing though, how can I filter the Worksheet names that has the same names within each workbooks? My approach is to add a new worksheet on the Output file but I can't see a code where I can get the Worksheet name of each same worksheets and use it as the Output worksheet name.

Comment: `$OutputSheet = $Dest.Worksheets.Add() 
$OutputSheet.Name = $currentSheet.Name`

This is what I did but obviously it didn't work...

Comment: @jeriru 
for the first comment, what do you mean "fileter"? To get the name of the sheet, `$currentSheetName = $currentSheet.Name` should work. Then, set the name of sheets, `$OutputSheet.Name = $currentSheetName` should work.

Comment: Hi @23whome, thank you for answering my questions :) I edited my post so I can clarify my question... It's about the error: _That name is already taken. Try a different one._ since I have worksheets that has same names.

Comment: Hey, @jeriru
why don't you get the all values (including names of sheets) and put those in variable(s)(maybe 2D array) first, then make new sheets in OutputFile and set values. I think it's easier and simpler.

Comment: `$Data = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()  ForEach ($SheetName in $currentSheetName) {  $Data += $SheetName`
Would this be right?

Comment: Since I don't know the structures of each sheets you have, I thought it's hard to suggest the way to put values in variables, so i add just the way to check if the same name exists.